# GUI application automation when no user logged in windows server 2016

Tags: c#, windows, remote-access, rpa

I am trying to automate Rumba TN3270 7.2 on windows server 2016(AWS) where my web application is also hosted.

I have written the VBA script which will do the automation on Rumba. To run the script I have to open the Rumba (.WDM file). We have wrapped the all code in simple console .net app and set that in task scheduler.

The task runs when we logged in but it does not run when user logged off. After 3 days found that GUI application won't run without kind of active session.

Is there anyway to run GUI automation using RDP or any login agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by using the following library

https://github.com/publee/FreeRDP-Sharp

We place the exe in startup which would communicate to server for automation request.

Whenever we need to do the automation we simply create the RDP session by using the above library. it works great